# Crear un DbSet<T> en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

estoy realizando un proyecto de C# utilizando EF Core 6 con Code First. Necesito ser capaz de crear un **DbSet<T>** en **tiempo de ejecución** en donde **T** sea una de las entidades de mi modelo. Para estoy estoy utilizando un string con el nombre de la entidad, por ejemplo, con el string **"Store"** (que puede ser enviado desde el frontend) quiero crear en tiempo de ejecución un **DbSet<Store>**.

He estado tratando de crear métodos con la Interfaz **IQueryable** y obtener un **DbSet dinámico**, pero obtengo errores al momento de ejecutar una consulta **Where** o el método **Include** de la clase DbSet. Necesito, por favor, que alguien me diga si es posible hacer algo como esto o necesito cambiar la logica de programación. (Una disculpa de antemano si me falta poner información).

Los métodos que ocupé se encuentran en los siguientes enlaces:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637924/dynamic-dbset-in-entity-framework-core
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533506/find-a-specified-generic-dbset-in-a-dbcontext-dynamically-when-i-have-an-entity#comment82296686_47464834 (Segunda respuesta)

Comment: Bienvenido/a a SOes. Creo que el escenario amerita `GraphQL`. Por otro lado, lecturas recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Veo 2 problemas en tu pregunta: (1) Crear un `DbSet<T>` en tiempo de ejecución, esto yo lo he hecho para incluir nuevas entidades a través de dll's, pero me parece que no es tu caso, tu ya tienes tu clases definidas o no??? Si las tienes definidas no necesitas crear nada en tiempo de ejecución y (2) Obtener el DbSet a partir de un string, esto que suena tan fácil es complejo y la manera de afrontarlo depende de lo que estes haciendo (así que requiere más explicación tu pregunta), porque en rigor no necesitas un string, lo que necesitas es el tipo T de dato y nada más.